# Long vs. BigInteger

Tags: java, performance, jvm, long-integer, bigdecimal

As I understand, I can abstract the precision away using the Number interface, which has Integer, Long and BigInteger implementations and plug the type I need depending on the range of my values. I understand the BigInteger is not ubiquitous because it takes more memory and less performant. What are the figures?

Comment: Why do you say `BigDecimal` and `double` are used for different purposes? And what are you trying to contrast?

Comment: `BigInteger` is, in fact, best compared to `double`.  But frankly any sort of "figures" would vary hugely depending on your platform.  (All this said: almost any decision about what datatype you should be using would depend on what sort of numbers you're storing, not performance needs.)

Comment: And frankly, generifying over `Number` is almost useless; there's almost no useful operations you can do with a generic `Number`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman do you mean `BigDecimal`?

Comment: @shmosel whoops, yes.  `BigDecimal` is best compared to `double`.

Comment: `long` is more performant than `Long`, but `BigInteger` is similar to `Long` for numbers which fix in both.

Answer (score 1):

***BigDecimal*** is similar to ***double***, it can help maintain precision and is useful for display purposes. Use it only when needed, otherwise *double* is better for many considerations (memory, performance).

It's useful for instance when storing money values: you want to keep the representation, as well as round the number right when doing sums (additions).

Comment: sorry, I have fixed my question

Comment: Alright, so you want benchmarks; I don't have these, but I agree with Louis who commented saying your criteria should be your design choice, not performance benchmarks. I'm not sure Number is very helpful to you. If you want to cut it short, just go ahead with BigDecimal, if your application isn't doing all these great operations on the values, and won't end up maxing up your CPU and memory.